# Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open C:\Users\Me\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_27_1.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, emulation, android-virtual-device

Until an hour ago, i was working fine using the emulator.
Suddenly a log error appear when i run the emulator and the app crash.
(minutes ago the emu was working perfectly).

Here's the log error:

> Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open
>   C:\Users\Me.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_27_1.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin:
>   Permission denied

The code is right, no mistakes, actually is the exactly same code i run minutes ago and the emulator was running perfectly.

*Does anyone was a fix for this?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you restart your system/run as admin already? I remember having similar things happen in the past, and they disappeared when after a restart. I suspect it's something in your OS rather than in android itself, but I'm not sure.

Comment: i did restart/run as admin but the log error is still there.

Comment: Well, by process of elimination something MUST be different from before. Perhaps you can use Android Studio's change history to figure out what, or git, or whatever versioning you are using to keep your change history. Computers are deterministic, so they will always perform the same actions under the exact same circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me: 
Go to the directory where your pstore.bin file is stored : (mine was this) 
C:\Users\USER_NAME.android\avd\ANDROID_EMULATOR_NAME\data\misc\pstore and uncheck the file's attribute named 'Read-only'. Click apply. Try re-using the emulator.

Comment: Apurwa thanks for your answer, i follow your advice, but still nothing. The solution that worked for me was to uninstall and reinstall again the whole android studio.

Comment: the attribute 'read-only' becomes checked again after running the emulator,is there a way to avoid it?